# How does job chaining behave in Laravel when there are multiple workers defined for a particular queue?

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs, chaining

According to the documentation, in order to execute a couple of jobs in sequence one may use the following approach:

```
Bus::chain([
    new ProcessPodcast,
    new OptimizePodcast,
    new ReleasePodcast,
])->dispatch();
```

What I didn't get from the documentation is if there's a guarantee that this jobs will run in sequence even when multiple workers are defined for that particular queue.

Anybody has experience with this and can confirm?